# xgb.cv() has unexpected behaviour

Tags: r, machine-learning, xgboost

I am using `xgboost v0.4.4` in R for a binary classification task. At some point I create an object:

```
cvData <- xgb.cv(a bunch of parameters)
```

Now, when I call `names(cvData)`, instead of getting (which is the expected behaviour):

```
## [1] "call"           "params"         "callbacks"      "evaluation_log"
## [5] "niter"          "folds"          "pred"
```

I get:

```
## [1] "dt"   "pred"
```

I am wondering whether there is a problem with `xgboost` in my machine. I am sure that there is no problem with the code, it has been tested on other machines and it works flawlessly. If anyone has dealt with this peculiar behavior, I would be appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Why are you using version v0.4.4 of xgboost? That's a really old version

Comment: @Richard The current version is quite slow.